# Efficiently Calculating Unique Online Agents with Multiple Skills Over Time Intervals in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, time-series, dax, data-modeling

I'm working with a Power BI data model that includes an agents table with the following structure:

AgentID (unique identifier for each agent)

Skill (each agent can have up to 15 different skills)

Login (datetime when the agent logged in)

Logout (datetime when the agent logged out)

For my analysis, I need to calculate the number of unique agents online during each time interval, with the ability to filter by Skill and datetime up to minute. Given that an agent can have multiple skills and multiple login/logout records, the complexity increases.

The challenge is to efficiently model this data or create a DAX measure that can provide the count of unique agents online during specific intervals, considering that expanding the data into a new row for each second of each agent's online time would result in an unmanageably large dataset.

I cannot afford to create a massive table with a row for every minute that each agent is online for each skill due to the dataset's size.

Has anyone faced a similar challenge and can suggest a data modeling approach or a DAX solution for Power BI that can handle this efficiently?

In my attempt to solve this issue, I created a DAX measure that aimed to count unique AgentIDs within each time interval, taking into account their Login and Logout times. I expected the measure to calculate the count of agents available during any given minute, allowing me to filter the results by Skill.

Here's the DAX measure I tried:

`dax ActiveAgents =  CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT('Agents'[AgentID]), FILTER( ALL('Calendar'[DateTime]), 'Calendar'[DateTime] >= MIN('Agents'[Login]) &&  'Calendar'[DateTime] <= MAX('Agents'[Logout]) ) )`
I expected this measure to provide a count of all unique agents who were logged in during each minute of the day across all skills. However, the result was not as expected. The measure only counted agents whose Login time matched the calendar minutes, but did not account for the span of time until their Logout.

I need a solution that accounts for the ongoing presence of an agent during their logged-in period and adjusts the unique count according to the skill filters applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching it around...

```
ActiveAgents = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Agents'[AgentID]), 
    FILTER(
      ALL('Agents'), 
     'Agents'[Login]) >= MIN('Calendar'[DateTime]) &&
     'Agents'[Logout]) <= MAX('Calendar'[DateTime])
    )
  )
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?